# Copy file from on site collection to another with powershell. Problem deleting local temp file

Tags: 2013, powershell

I'm trying to copy a file from one site collection to another. I download my file to my local server and then upload it to the target site. My problem is that in the last step, the temporary local file cannot be deleted.

That's the error message shown:

> Remove-Item : Cannot remove item c:\temp\custom.js: The process cannot access the file 'c:\temp\custom.js' because it is being used by another process.

Here's my script:

```
# config
$fromsite = "http://sharepoint/teamsite_template/"
$fromfile = "scriptlibrary/custom.js"
$tosite = "http://sharepoint/teamsite1/"
$tofile = "scriptlibrary/custom.js"
$localfile   = "c:\temp\custom.js"

$overWriteExisting = $True #or add new version if versioning enabled

#get remote file
$web = Get-SPWeb $fromsite
$file = $web.GetFile($fromfile)
$filebytes = $file.OpenBinary()

# create local copy of file
$filestream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($localfile, "Create")
$binarywriter = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($filestream)
$binarywriter.write($filebytes)
$binarywriter.Close()

# do a little SharePoint setup
$web = Get-SPWeb $tosite
$files = $web.GetFolder($library).Files

# read the local file
$data = Get-ChildItem $localfile

# add any needed metadata
$metadata = @{}

#checkout file before uploading
$file = $web.GetFile($tofile)
$file.CheckOut()

# do the upload (the following is one line)
$newfile = $files.Add($tofile, $data.OpenRead(), $metadata, $overWriteExisting)

# check in new file
$newfile.CheckIn("new version", 1);

# 
If (Test-Path $localfile){
    Remove-Item $localfile
}
```

Any tipps on how to improve that script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
# do the upload
$fileStream = $data.OpenRead()
$newfile = $files.Add($tofile, $fileStream, $metadata, $overWriteExisting)
$fileStream.Close()
```